How to read into a csv file in tensorflow
I am carrying out machine learning in conda environment using tensorflow. Within my code, the problem occurs as I try to read into my train.csv and test.csv as the code below shows:
os.environ['TF_CPP_MIN_LOG_LEVEL'] = '2'
import tensorflow as tf
from tensorflow import keras
from tensorflow.keras import layers, regularizers
from tensorflow.keras.datasets import mnist
import pandas as pd
from tensorflow.keras.optimizers.legacy import Adam

#HYPER PARAMETERS

BATCH_SIZE = 64
WEIGHT_DECAY = 0.001
LEARNING_RATE = 0.001

train_df = pd.read_csv("train.csv")
test_df = pd.read_csv("test.csv")
train_images = os.getcwd() + "/train_images/" + train_df.iloc[:, 0].values
test_images = os.getcwd() + "/test_images/" + test_df.iloc[:, 0].values

train_labels = train_df.iloc[:, 1:].values
test_labels =  test_df.iloc[:, 1:].values

def read_image(image_path, label):
  image = tf.io.read_file(image_path)
  image = tf.image.decode_image(image, channels=1, dtype=tf.float32)

  image.set_shape((64, 64, 1))
  label[0].set_shape([])
  label[1].set_shape([])

  labels = {"first_num": label[0], "second_num": label[1]}
  return image, labels

AUTOTUNE = tf.data.experimental.AUTOTUNE
train_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices(
  (train_images, train_labels)
)
train_dataset = (
  train_dataset.shuffle(buffer_size=len(train_labels))
  .map(read_image)
  .batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

test_dataset = tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((test_images, test_labels))
test_dataset = (
  test_dataset.map(read_image)
  .batch(batch_size=BATCH_SIZE)
  .prefetch(buffer_size=AUTOTUNE)
)

inputs = keras.Input(shape= (64, 64, 1))
x = layers.Conv2D(
  filters=32,
  kernel_size=3,
  padding='same',
  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(WEIGHT_DECAY),
)(inputs)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.activations.relu(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(
  64, 3, kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(WEIGHT_DECAY),
)(x)
x = layers.BatchNormalization()(x)
x = keras.activations.relu(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Conv2D(
  64,
  3,
  activation='relu',
  kernel_regularizer=regularizers.l2(WEIGHT_DECAY),
)(x)

x= layers.Conv2D(128, 3, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.MaxPooling2D()(x)
x = layers.Flatten()(x)
x = layers.Dense(128, activation='relu')(x)
x = layers.Dropout(0.5)(x)
x = layers.Dense(64, activation='relu')(x)
output1 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='first_num')(x)
output2 = layers.Dense(10, activation='softmax', name='second_num')(x)
model = keras.Model(inputs=inputs, outputs=[output1, output2])

print(model.summary())

model.compile(
  loss=[keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        keras.losses.SparseCategoricalCrossentropy(),
        ],
  metrics=["accuracy", "accuracy"],
)

model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, verbose=2)
model.evaluate(train_dataset, verbose=2)

The error begins with...

2024-05-06 06:09:12.539105: E external/local_tsl/tsl/platform/windows/windows_file_system.cc:363] ERROR: GetSymbolicLinkTarget cannot open file for \\?\C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda\train_images\129_97.png GetLastError: 2


The Error following is similar for the different images to be read and ends with:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda\main.py", line 94, in <module>
    model.fit(train_dataset, epochs=5, verbose=2)
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\tf_cpu\Lib\site-packages\keras\src\utils\traceback_utils.py", line 123, in error_handler
    raise e.with_traceback(filtered_tb) from None
  File "C:\Users\USER\anaconda3\envs\tf_cpu\Lib\site-packages\tensorflow\python\eager\execute.py", line 53, in quick_execute
    tensors = pywrap_tfe.TFE_Py_Execute(ctx._handle, device_name, op_name,
  ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
tensorflow.python.framework.errors_impl.NotFoundError: Graph execution error:

Detected at node ReadFile defined at (most recent call last):
<stack traces unavailable>
NewRandomAccessFile failed to Create/Open: C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda/train_images/129_97.png : The system cannot find the file specified.
; No such file or directory
     [[{{node ReadFile}}]]
     [[IteratorGetNext]] [Op:__inference_one_step_on_iterator_2745]


Please how may I resolve this?

Does the file C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda/train_images/129_97.png exist?

You mix \  and / in your path (which could be fine, but I'd change it), and also use single \  instead of \\ '. Single \  are escape characters for specials, like \n  for newline. \  can also be used to escape such behaviour and treat the next character as normal, so \\  is interpreted as "one normal string ". Try to use os.path.join(path1, path2) to extend your image paths. Beware that path2 must not start with /, otherwise path1 will be ignored.

To give an example, your path should look loke 'C:\\Users\\USER\\CODE\\PycharmProjects\\pythonProject2Conda/train_images/129_97.png'. Which you get e.g. with os.path.join(r'C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda', 'train_images', '129_97.png')

(!) [link](C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda/train_images/129_97.png  really) Really does not exist. However, png files are listed in a csv file I downloaded from Kaggle.com a database site.

The csv file (located in C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda\test_images\test.csv)   have png files just llisted like this                                                  Image first_num second_num
0_00.png 0 0
100_00.png 0 0
101_00.png 0 0
102_00.png 0 0
103_00.png 0 0
104_00.png 0 0
105_00.png 0 0
106_00.png 0 0
107_00.png 0 0
108_00.png 0 0
109_00.png 0 0
10_00.png 0 0
110_00.png 0 0
111_00.png 0 0
I am just following a tutorial and I may have some mixup here which was not well explained. I would really appreciate more amelioration of the problems in code.

(2) In response to the second corrective comment on the error codes: I used the prescribed train_images = os.path.join(r'C:\Users\USER\CODE\PycharmProjects\pythonProject2Conda') +"/test_images/"+ train_df.iloc[:, 0].values.                              But still encountered same error
